# Can I read a timezone offset in minutes using TO_TIMESTAMP in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, timestamp

Ok, I'm trying to convert a varchar column to a timestamp in Oracle.

The data all seems to be in the form '2012-02-01 11h35m34s 360', which is fine except for that 360 at the end. The vast majority of the records end in '360'. I'm in central time, which is 6 hours from GMT, so I'm assuming that's the timezone offset in minutes (for some reason).

I'm looking for a good way to read that offset in TO_TIMESTAMP(), or for any other good way to deal with it. I haven't been able to find any info on anything other than the standard offset format.

Comment: Are you intending to retain the zimezone info, in a TIMESTAMP WITH [LOCAL] TIMEZONE? Otherwise if it is already in your local timezone, what will you do with the value - are there times you want to 'adjust'?

Comment: That's a funky format - never seen that one before.  Somewhere there invent it?  You may have to parse it apart yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen it before either. We just gained access to an external database that I'm going to have to import from. Some of their data is pretty hideous (There's an 'age' field containing dates in various formats. Ugh).

And, I'm not really planning on retaining the timezone info, but I can't guarantee that it's actually in my local time. It just seems like most of it is...

Comment: I would retain the timezone offset if you can.  At least the format is readable.  It's just the separators that are funky, and the offset being in whole number of minutes, rather than HHMM or HH:MM format.  Other than that, it's pretty close to ISO.

Comment: I would verify that your assumption is correct before writing any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the data in Oracle with the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` datatype, as described [in these docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081).

It took me a bit of digging to put this together, but here are functions that you can use to do the conversion.  (Disclaimer: I don't do a lot with Oracle, so there may be more optimal ways to do this.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION minutes_to_offset (minutes IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(-minutes / 60)) || ':' ||
         LPAD(TO_CHAR(ABS(MOD(minutes,60))),2,'0');
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytimestamp (ts IN VARCHAR)
RETURN TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN FROM_TZ(
    TO_TIMESTAMP (SUBSTR(ts, 0, 20), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24"h"MI"m"SS"s"')
  , minutes_to_offset(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ts,22))));
END;
```

Then you can just use that function against your fields

```
mytimestamp('2012-02-01 11h35m34s 360')
```

[Here is a working SQL Fiddle to demonstrate.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/749ff/3)

Comment: Looks like that should do it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This example assumes the same format for all dates. You can convert the date part further to_date() or to_timestamp() then concat. it with 360 or any other number:

```
-- Can use To_Timestamp instead of To_Date --
 SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')||' '||360 Final_Date
   FROM
   (
   SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('2012-02-01 11h35m34s', 'h', ':'), 'm', ':'), 's', '') dt 
     FROM dual
   )
  /
```

Output:

```
2012-02-01 11:35:34 360
```

Comment: You don't need the `replace` calls, you can leave the fixed values in as double-quoted elements as Matt showed. I think you're missing the point a bit though; you're adding `360` on the end of the string (after a pointless double conversion, since your replace has already got it in the format you use both ways), but the OP's original string already has `360`, and it needs to end up as a timestamp, not as another string.

Comment: This is how I understood the problem. If I missing smth then it was not explained clearly. I also mentioned substr() in my post. I see no problem cut/replace values and convert the string into timestamp... True, I was not sure what OP wanted to do with 360. But I personally think that even "pointless" posts may give you a good idea somtimes. Thank you.

Comment: But you aren't converting it into a timestamp, which is why I thought you'd got the wrong idea. The OP is *starting* with a string with `360` on the end. I wasn't trying to be nasty; I didn't say the post was pointless, only that `to_char(to_date(str, fmt), fmt)` is pointless since you end up with exactly what you started with. Your inner select already gives you `2012-02-01 11:35:34`, and you end up with that still after the conversion to/from a date type. The replace part is useful on its own (but not here 8-), so I'm really not trying to put the whole thing down.

Comment: Alex, I mentioned in my post that it can be converted further. I think sharing the ideas is important, not do all the conversions for the OP's. As I wrote I was not sure what OP wanted to do with that number at the end. The simplest way is probably to cut this number from the string, do the conversion, then append that number... This was my way of thinking. It also can be converted to some form of time, lk hours, minutes, secs... I admit, I was not sure how to handle that part, what needs to be done with that number... But now the OP has both examples and hopefully it helped.